# python numpy array change dimension depends on the number of elements

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to convert numpy array x of shape (7,50,2) into shape(7,2450) by performing some simple operation - code below (might not be optimal but should work).

X table is a pairs of numbers from 1 to 28 as example

```
[[[ 7 10]  
  [25 13]  
  [ 2 12]  
  [ 8 15]  
  [21 11]
```

My problem is that depending on a 2nd dim the code produce different results.

Code to illustrate the problem:

```
points = 50    
x = np.random.randint(1, 28, (7,points,2))
x2 = np.random.rand(7,points,2)
main_arr = []
```

us above two sample tables with points = 50 and output for 'x' would be

```
< class 'numpy.ndarray' >  
(7,)
```

for 'x2'

```
< class 'numpy.ndarray' >  
(7, 2450)    



for arr in x:
    iterations = arr.shape[0]
    tmp_arr = []
    for z in range(iterations):
        vectorA = np.array([arr[z][0], arr[z][1]])
        for y in arr:
            if not np.array_equal(vectorA, y):
                vectorB = np.array([y[0], y[1]])
                var1 = np.dot(vectorA,vectorB)
                tmp_arr.append(var1)
    main_arr.append(np.array(tmp_arr))

result = np.array(main_arr)
print(type(result))
print(result.shape)
```

However and here is where I'm lost, use exact same code but only with `point = 10` and on my PC print(result.shape) for 'x' outputs sometimes `(7,)` sometimes `(7,90)` while for 'x2' always `(7,90)`

*when I write sometimes than it means I'm executing code with no changes one after another.

Any help understanding why is that much appreciated !

Evo

Comment: The shape of `x` and `x2` is (7,50,2)

Comment: Look at `main_arr`.  That should be a list of arrays.  Do those arrays vary in shape?  If so `result` can only be a (7,) object array, essentially just that list of arrays.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to just use `x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)`?